# Ci sono differenze di uso tra "assieme" e "insieme"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

Nel racconto *I barattoli* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> "Ripensava agli anni in cui, con molto decoro, lavorava come commesso presso un'importante compagnia di assicurazioni, rivedeva la sua casa viva e rumorosa, con i figli che studiavano *assieme* e *assieme* giocavano."

Non conoscevo il vocabolo "assieme", ma cercando il suo [significato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assieme/) mi sembra molto simile a la parola "insieme", che sì conoscevo. La mia domanda è: questi due termini sono completamente equivalenti o ci sono invece differenze di uso tra loro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/assieme-o-insieme_(La_grammatica_italiana)/), "assieme" ed "insieme" non presentano alcuna differenza di significato e possono essere usati indifferentemente.
L'unica eccezione a questa regola è l'insieme matematico, per il quale non esiste il corrispondente con "assieme"; inoltre in espressioni come "Per un insieme di ragioni" l'uso di "assieme" in vece di "insieme" è difficilmente riscontrabile.

Comment: Questo l'ho capito, ma io vi chiedo sulle differenze di uso.

Comment: @Charo essendo equivalenti non ne hanno, ho aggiornato la mia risposta

Comment: Giusto, per quanto riguarda gli avverbi _insieme_ e _assieme_. Ma i sostantivi _insieme_ ed _assieme_? _L'insieme_ = _the set_, mentre _l'assieme_ = _the whole_?

Comment: @MauroVanetti sempre secondo il Treccani, non c'è differenza neanche per i due sostantivi, a meno che per "insieme" non si intenda quello matematico: ho aggiornato la mia risposta

Comment: @Stubborn Non mi limiterei alla matematica. Si può dire _Non stiamo più insieme per un insieme di ragioni_ ma mi sembrerebbe strano dire _Non stiamo più assieme per un assieme di ragioni_...

Comment: @MauroVanetti Hai ragione per quanto riguarda *per un assieme di ragioni*, ma perchè *non stiamo più assieme* è errato? Ogni tanto lo sento dire...

Comment: Posso pregare di non generalizzare da quello che suona “strano” a ognuno di noi a concetti come “percepita come strana dai parlanti italiani”? Un'affermazione così ampia richiederebbe qualche supporto. A me, per esempio, suona “strano” dire “seguitare” per “proseguire”, mentre per molti altri è più naturale così.

Comment: @DaG è vero, ho aggiornato la mia risposta

Comment: The word "insieme" in the sentence "Per un insieme di ragioni" can easily be translated into the English "For a whole set of reasons", and carries precisely the same meaning as that of a mathematical set, although perhaps from a somewhat abstract point of view. Personally, I find that something like "insieme a te" is much easier to pronounce than "assieme a te", perhaps other Italian speakers can confirm this (or alternatively provide a counterargument).